# IndexError: index 29 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 29

Tags: python, deep-learning, time-series, data-science, forecasting

I'm working on Time series forecasting using the Transformers Model (Deep Learning). I am using code I pulled from github. When I run the code I'm always getting an error that says: IndexError: index 29 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 29.[code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvzbV.png)

Anyone can help me to solve this problem, I'm a beginner in this field.

Thank you.

Comment: Size 29 means 28 index is max

Answer (score 0):

If the length of your data structure is 29, the last index you can access is 28. Remember that index starts at 0.

Answer (score 0):

1. This error happens when you try to use a column index value does not
   exist as it is outside the index values for the columns that are in
   the data set.
2. If this error does occur always check the expected index values for
   each column and compare against what you are trying to return.